# Stop script within forked process

Tags: ruby

I have

```
backupCommand = "rsync #{rsyncOptions} #{directory} #{backupSSH}:#{@backupPath}"
pid = fork {   
  system backupCommand
  Kernel.trap('INT') {
    Kernel.exit
  }   
}   
Process.detach(pid)
```

What I want to happen is, if the script runs and I want to stop it, a ctrl-c should kill the script and all process it forked.

Comment: After you detach a process there is not way to send `INT` from keyboard except for explicit `kill`

Answer (score 0):

As @Victor Moroz points out, a detached process can't receive ^C from your keyboard.  If your foreground is still running doing other work, it can remember the detached pid and send it a kill signal when it receives the SIGINT. Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby                                             

got_sigint = false
backupCommand = "/usr/bin/env sleep 5"
pid = spawn backupCommand

Process.detach(pid)
puts "detached #{pid}"

Kernel.trap('INT') {
  got_sigint = true
}

until got_sigint
  system "ps -p #{pid}"
  sleep 1
end

if got_sigint
  begin Process.kill('KILL',pid) rescue Errno::ESRCH end
  sleep 1
  system "ps -p #{pid}"
end
```

If I run this and wait > 5 seconds, you see the spawned process exits naturally:

```
detached 8565
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 8565 pts/1    00:00:00 sleep
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 8565 pts/1    00:00:00 sleep
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 8565 pts/1    00:00:00 sleep
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 8565 pts/1    00:00:00 sleep
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 8565 pts/1    00:00:00 sleep
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
^C  PID TTY          TIME CMD
```

If I run again and send ^C before 5 seconds, the foreground process catches the sigint and kills the background one:

```
detached 8588
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 8588 pts/1    00:00:00 sleep
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 8588 pts/1    00:00:00 sleep
^C  PID TTY          TIME CMD
```